# Unsupported operand type python

Tags: python, pandas, string, typeerror, unsupportedoperation

`if((pd['data'].str.startswith('aha' | 'bou')) & (pd[‘data1’].str.startswith(‘aha’|’bou’)))`
I am using pandas I want to read from dataframe and  append data which starts with aha and bou in two columns to the list. While checking the condition I am getting

TypeError : unsupported operand type(s) for |: ‘str’ and ‘str’

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `|` operator in this way in Python.
You will have to compare both instances seperately as far as I know. Here is a working version.

```
if ((pd["data"].str.startswith("aha") | pd["data1"].str.startswith("bou")) & (pd["data1"].str.startswith("aha") | pd["data1"].str.startswith("bou")))
```

Comment: I tried doing this it throws an error saying “the truth value is ambiguos .use a.empty(),a.bool(),a.item(),a.any() or a.all().”

Comment: Hmm, could you provide the data you are using for `pd` please?

Answer (score 0):

You can create boolean mask by tuples instead `|`, output is boolean mask:

```
m = pd['data'].str.startswith(('aha', 'bou')) & pd['data1'].str.startswith(('aha', 'bou'))
```

Comment: I tried doing this it throws an error saying “the truth value is ambiguos .use a.empty(),a.bool(),a.item(),a.any() or a.all().”

Comment: @Gkyr - Problem is in your code, cannot use `if` here, maybe help [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/gotchas.html#using-if-truth-statements-with-pandas) for explain why.